# Gaps and Island problem - SQL Server - Snapshot model

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am having source data like this:

Scenario 1:

| as_of_date | issue_id | issue_status_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation |
| 9/2/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation |
| 9/3/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/4/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/5/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/6/2020 | 123456 |  |
| 9/7/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/8/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/9/2020 | 123456 | Closed |
| 9/10/2020 | 123456 | Closed |

this query is giving correct values:

Basically when status in pending validation or closed

https://dbfiddle.uk/YRJPI8DW

````
(select
as_of_date,
issue_id,
issue_status_name,
row_number() over (partition by issue_id order by as_of_date) - row_number() over (partition by issue_id, output_flag order by as_of_date) as grp
,output_flag
from issues cross apply
(values (case when issue_status_name in ('Pending Validation', 'Closed')
then 1 else 0 end)) v(output_flag)
)
select
as_of_date,
issue_id,
issue_status_name,
case when output_flag = 1 then min(as_of_date) over (partition by issue_id, grp) end as desired_output
from cte
order by as_of_date```
````

Scenario 2:

when previous status = pending sustaibility and current status in (validation or closed) we get that records asofdt and carry forward

we set null when reverse happens like desired output

| as_of_date | issue_id | issue_status_name | Prev_status_name | Desired_Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2020 | 456789 | Pending Validation | NULL | NULL |
| 9/2/2020 | 456789 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | NULL |
| 9/3/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Pending Validation | NULL |
| 9/4/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | NULL |
| 9/5/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | NULL |
| 9/6/2020 | 456789 | Pending Sustainability | Closed | NULL |
| 9/7/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Pending Sustainability | 9/7/2020 |
| 9/8/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 |
| 9/9/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 |
| 9/10/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 |

I tried this query but it gives completely wrong output:
https://dbfiddle.uk/NskgiHL3

```
(select
as_of_date,
issue_id,
issue_status_name,
row_number() over (partition by issue_id order by as_of_date) - row_number() over (partition by issue_id, output_flag order by as_of_date) as grp
,output_flag
  from issues cross apply
(values (case when issue_status_name in ('Pending Validation', 'Closed') and prev_status_name = 'Pending Sustainability'
then 1 else 0 end)) v(output_flag)
)
select
as_of_date,
issue_id,
issue_status_name,
case when output_flag = 1 then min(as_of_date) over (partition by issue_id, grp) end as desired_output
from cte
```

Comment: is this a mistake or Closed row for the same issue_id can appear multiple times? and for all of them you expect in Desired_Output to see the latest Pending Sustainability date?

Comment: Its not a mistake. the data is actually stacked daily even if status or nothing changed in the row.

Basically we need to find gaps where prev is pending sustain and curent status is pendin validation and closed. And need to carry that gap as long as status doesnt change back to pending sustainability

Comment: also take in mind- your `as_of_date` is not a defined as date (nor formatted properly)- so when ordering results by this field, it will end up by strange order result... for example "9/10/2020" will appear before "9/2/2020"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fixed your date format (but it's better to insert it properly in the first place) - `fixed_date`
2. I found the latest row which changed to Close, for each issue_id - `latest_close`
3. If the latest_close date is past (or equal) to current - show it - `case`

```
with cte as
(
    select  *
    from    issues
    outer apply
    (
        select convert(date,as_of_date, 101) as fixed_date
    )   as fix
)

select      curr.*,
            case
                when latest_close.fixed_date <= curr.fixed_date
                then latest_close.fixed_date
            end     as res

from        cte     as curr

outer apply
(
    select  top(1)
            latest_close.*
    from    cte     as  latest_close
    where   latest_close.issue_id = curr.issue_id
    and     latest_close.issue_status_name = 'Closed'
    and     latest_close.Prev_status_name <> 'Closed'
    order by latest_close.fixed_date desc
)   as      latest_close

order by    curr.issue_id, curr.fixed_date
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/AcXykMFV

| as_of_date | issue_id | issue_status_name | Prev_status_name | Desired | fixed_date | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2020 | 456789 | Pending Validation | null | null | 2020-09-01 | null |
| 9/2/2020 | 456789 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | null | 2020-09-02 | null |
| 9/3/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Pending Validation | null | 2020-09-03 | null |
| 9/4/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | null | 2020-09-04 | null |
| 9/5/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | null | 2020-09-05 | null |
| 9/6/2020 | 456789 | Pending Sustainability | Closed | null | 2020-09-06 | null |
| 9/7/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Pending Sustainability | 9/7/2020 | 2020-09-07 | 2020-09-07 |
| 9/8/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-09-07 |
| 9/9/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 | 2020-09-09 | 2020-09-07 |
| 9/10/2020 | 456789 | Closed | Closed | 9/7/2020 | 2020-09-10 | 2020-09-07 |

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure if this will work. i will test it out. 

Because I see that code doesn't look for pending sustainability anywhere. I will research and get back.

Comment: I didn't specify this specific status, you can change `Prev_status_name <> 'Closed'` to `Prev_status_name = 'Pending Sustainability'`

Comment: Thanks Yair, this works. I added the conditions according to my needs and works. I still need to thoroughly test it but should work.

Comment: Yair, I checked and it doesn't work. 

we need to set the date when prev status in sustainability and current status in validation, closed)

null should be when issue status in (sustainbility) and prev status in (validation, closed)

Comment: just add this conditions to the CASE... also, the query can be simplified if moving from "Pending Sustainability" to "Closed" may happen only 1 time, but I wasn't sure if this is the case

Comment: Yes Yarin, it can happen N number of times. Status can keep switching.

Comment: Here, take a look at this query https://dbfiddle.uk/4MVn4gHX - the `res` field matches your `Desired_Output`... if something is incorrect, please explain or add sample data to show it

Answer (score 0):

Would an approach like this work for you, using LAG and a MIN?:

```
    WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        as_of_date,
        issue_id,
        issue_status_name,
        LAG(issue_status_name) OVER (PARTITION BY issue_id ORDER BY as_of_date) AS prev_status_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY issue_id ORDER BY as_of_date) - 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY issue_id, output_flag ORDER BY as_of_date) AS grp,
        output_flag
    FROM issues
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN issue_status_name IN ('Pending Validation', 'Closed') AND prev_status_name = 'Pending Sustainability' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) v(output_flag)
)
SELECT
    cte.as_of_date,
    cte.issue_id,
    cte.issue_status_name,
    CASE
        WHEN cte.output_flag = 1 THEN
            ISNULL(
                (SELECT MIN(as_of_date) FROM cte c WHERE c.issue_id = cte.issue_id AND c.grp = cte.grp AND c.prev_status_name = 'Pending Sustainability'),
                'NULL'
            )
    END AS desired_output
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.as_of_date;
```

Comment: That kind of works but problem is 9/7 date should be carried to 9/8, 9/9